# Values written to new worksheet not getting saved

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have the following script:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True  'set to False for production
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\XXXSample_Data.xlsx") 'xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("XXXXX")
Set objRE1 = New RegExp
    With objRE1
        .Pattern    = "Invalid Response received from system"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global     = False
    End With

    Set objRE2 = New RegExp

    With objRE2
       .Pattern    = "Enterprise Data mapping cannot be found"
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Global     = False
    End With

    Set objRE3 = New RegExp

    With objRE3
       .Pattern    = "Caught exception and rethrowingError detected"
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Global     = False
    End With

    xf = 0
    re = 0
    gg = 0
    rst = 0

    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns(11).Cells 
        str = cell.Value
        If objRE1.Test( str ) Then
                xf = xf + 1
        Elseif objRE2.Test( str ) Then
                re = re + 1
        Elseif  objRE3.Test( str ) Then
                gg = gg + 1
        Else
                rst = rst + 1
        End If      
    Next

    Set objWorksheet = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    objWorksheet.Cells(5,5).Value  = "Invalid Response received from system "
    objWorksheet.Cells(6,5).Value  = "Enterprise Data mapping cannot be found "
    objWorksheet.Cells(7,5).Value  = "Caught exception and rethrowingError detected "
    objWorksheet.Cells(8,5).Value  = "Errors With new String patterns found "

    'WScript.Echo xf
    objWorksheet.Cells(5,6).Value = xf 
    objWorksheet.Cells(6,6).Value = re 
    objWorksheet.Cells(7,6).Value = gg
    objWorksheet.Cells(8,6).Value = rst

    wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close

Set objRE1 = Nothing
Set objRE2 = Nothing
xl.Quit
```

The values in the second sheet is not getting written or saved.

Another point - I see the file was getting saved under "My Documents" somehow. may be that also someone can point out.

Answer (score 1):

```
wb.Save
wb.Close true, "C:\XXXSample_Data.xlsx"
```

Setting `wb.Saved = True` marks the workbook as saved without saving it.

The parameters to `Close` are: save changes (`true`) and path to the file where the changes will be saved